# Putting c# inside xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am using WinForms. I have an XML document that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MarcusXMLFile xmlns:Responses="http://www.rewardstrike.com/XMLFile1.xml">
  <response>
    <greatmood>
      <yes>
        <replytocommand>
          <answer>Yes.</answer>
          <answer>Yes, sir.</answer>
          <answer>Settings.Default.User</answer>
        </replytocommand>
      </yes>
    </greatmood>
  </response>
</MarcusXMLFile>
```

To read this xml document, I use:

```
private void Responses()
    {
        string query = String.Format("http://www.rewardstrike.com/XMLFile1.xml");
        XmlDocument Responses = new XmlDocument();
        Responses.Load(query);

        XmlNode channel = Responses.SelectSingleNode("MarcusXMLFile");



        if (QEvent == "yesreplytocommand")
        {

            XmlNodeList yesreplytocommand = Responses.SelectNodes("MarcusXMLFile/response/greatmood/yes/replytocommand/answer");
            foreach (XmlNode ans in yesreplytocommand
                        .Cast<XmlNode>()
                        .OrderBy(elem => Guid.NewGuid()))
                    {
                        response = ans.InnerText;
                    }
        }
    }
```

and then to display:

```
QEvent = "yesreplytocommand";
Responses();
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

My problem is when it gets Settings.Default.User and displays it, I want it to display it as c# code so that it actually gets the value from the application. Right now it is actually displaying "Settings.Default.User". How do I do this?

Comment: So you want to evaluate `Settings.Default.User` at runtime? If you do, is `Settings` is a class?

Comment: You would need some way to distinguish a normal text answer with a function-answer. How do you want to approach this?

Comment: gunr2171, I don't know of any ways to approach this. I'm still new to c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you'll need a way to recognize which of your entries are literals and which are expressions. You could do it by adding an attribute to the XML node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MarcusXMLFile xmlns:Responses="http://www.rewardstrike.com/XMLFile1.xml">
  <response>
    <greatmood>
      <yes>
        <replytocommand>
          <answer>Yes.</answer>
          <answer>Yes, sir.</answer>
          <answer expression="true">DefaultSettings.User</answer>
        </replytocommand>
      </yes>
    </greatmood>
  </response>
</MarcusXMLFile>
```

Based on that you can modify your parsing code to either directly use the value from XML or evaluate it instead:

```
foreach (XmlNode ans in yesreplytocommand
    .Cast<XmlNode>()
    .OrderBy(elem => Guid.NewGuid()))
        {
            var attribute = ans.Attributes["expression"];
            if (attribute != null && attribute.Value == "true")
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Evaluate(ans.InnerText));
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ans.InnerText);
            }
        }
```

There's still the problem of evaluating that expression. There's no easy built-in way to do that from C#. But you could use [Dynamic Expresso](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DynamicExpresso.Core). This is how `Evaluate` method could look like:

```
public string Evaluate(string expression)
{
    var interpreter = new Interpreter();
    interpreter.SetVariable("DefaultSettings", Settings.Default);
    return interpreter.Eval<string>(expression);
}
```

As you can see, you'll still have to define the expression variables yourself. For the above to work, you will have to use `DefaultSettings.User` in your XML instead of `Settings.Default.User`. I already made that change in my sample XML at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: I installed 'Dynamic Expresso' and have changed all the code, but then when I run the program, it is saying that is does not recognize 'Default' in  `return interpreter.Eval<string>("Default.User");`

Comment: @Cody_T Sorry about that. I fixed that line in my answer now. I forgot to change it before pasting it in my answer.

Comment: Works great! You did an excellent job explaining how to do it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at XML Serialization.

Really basic on how it works is that it can convert a struct or a class like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int bar = 0;
    Vector2 obj = new Vector2(10, 50);
}
```

into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
<bar>0</bar>
<obj>
    <X>10</X>
    <Y>50</Y>
</ojb>
</Foo>
```

And the other way around.
The methods used to load and save code looks like this:

```
public static void Save(string filepath, Foo foobject)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, foobject);
    }
}

public static Foo Load(string filepath)
{
    Foo myFoo;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo));
    using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead(filepath))
    {
        myFoo = (Foo)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

It converts xml code to c# code, and other way around.
It cannot convert methods, but it can convert most properties and classes.